# sublime GIT can't push or pull

Tags: git, push, sublimetext3, pull

I just switched to Sublime and I try to set up git but I can't push or pull to/from remote  repository and seems to be related to the path of SSH key. If I use command line everything works fine.

If I use command-line the path to SSH  looks

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

How do I add to sublime GIT Package the correct SSH keys path

console log

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: What exactly is the error in Sublime? You can take a look at the python console in sublime via `View > Show Console` or alternativly with the shortcut `CTRL+\``.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I made an update on my post

Comment: Which plugin are you using with sublime for git?

Answer (score 1):

When your ssh key has a passphrase and you try push/pull with this plugin, we don't have an interactive shell that can request the passphrase. A known workaround is to use a keychain to autofill the passphrase.  [Sublime-text-git/issues/178](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/178)

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command: `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to permanently add the id_rsa ssh private key to your local. Enter your passphrase once and won't be asked for the passphrase again.